Approximate Solution for Fisher Information
The original problem had an error, which I have now realized. So, how should I proceed to calculate the approximate Fisher information? I am unable to derive a good expression for it.

original problem
I am trying to compute the contribution to the Fisher information from jump points $b_i(\theta)$ in the convolved function $f(x; \theta)$ with respect to the parameter $\theta$. I am unsure whether it is correct to perform the integration over a small interval around each $b_i(\theta)$. Below is my thought process and derivation.
We define a piecewise probability density function $p(x; \theta)$ as:
$$
p(x; \theta) =
\begin{cases}
a_1(\theta), & b_0(\theta) < x < b_1(\theta), \\
a_2(\theta), & b_1(\theta) < x < b_2(\theta), \\
a_3(\theta), & b_2(\theta) < x < b_3(\theta).
\end{cases}
$$
Now, consider the convolution of $p(x; \theta)$ with a standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$, which yields a new probability density function:
$$
f(x; \theta) = p * \phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \int_{b_{i-1}(\theta)}^{b_i(\theta)} a_i(\theta) \phi(x - y) \, dy
= \sum_{i=1}^{3} a_i(\theta) \left[ \Phi(x - b_{i-1}(\theta)) - \Phi(x - b_i(\theta)) \right]
$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal probability density function, and $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal.
The partial derivative of $f(x; \theta)$ with respect to $\theta$ is:
$$
\frac{\partial f(x; \theta)}{\partial \theta} = \sum_{i=1}^{3} \left( \frac{\partial a_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \left[ \Phi(x - b_{i-1}(\theta)) - \Phi(x - b_i(\theta)) \right] 
+ a_i(\theta) \left[ -\phi(x - b_i(\theta)) \frac{\partial b_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta} + \phi(x - b_{i-1}(\theta)) \frac{\partial b_{i-1}(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \right] \right)
$$
The contribution to the Fisher information at the jump point $b_i(\theta)$ is approximated using $\Phi(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\phi(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, with:
$$
\Phi\left( b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta) \right) \approx \Phi(0) + \phi(0) \left( b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta) \right)
$$
The Fisher information at $b_i(\theta)$ is given by:
$$
I_{b_i} = \int_{b_i(\theta) - \delta}^{b_i(\theta) + \delta} \left( \frac{\partial f(x; \theta)}{\partial \theta} \right)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{f(x; \theta)} \, dx,
$$
which I approximate as:
$$
I_{b_i} \approx 2 \delta \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{3} \left( \frac{\partial a_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \left[ \Phi(b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta)) - \frac{1}{2} \right] + a_i(\theta) \left[ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\partial b_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta} + \phi(b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta)) \frac{\partial b_{i-1}(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \right] \right) \right]^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{3} a_i(\theta) \left[ \Phi(b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta)) - \frac{1}{2} \right]}
$$
Finally, simplifying further, we obtain:
$$
I_{b_i} \approx 2 \delta \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{3} \frac{\partial a_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta} ( b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta) ) + a_i(\theta) \left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\partial b_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta} + \phi(b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta)) \frac{\partial b_{i-1}(\theta)}{\partial \theta} \right) \right]^2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sum_{i=1}^{3} a_i(\theta) ( b_i(\theta) - b_{i-1}(\theta) )}
$$
My question is: Is my approximation for the Fisher information correct? Specifically, is it valid to integrate over a small interval around $b_i(\theta)$, and are there improvements or better approaches to computing the Fisher information at these jump points?

What is "the Fisher information at [the] jump points"?

This expression is indeed quite vague. I believe that most of the Fisher information is concentrated around ( b_i ), so I want to calculate it there.

If $p(x;\theta)$ is not continuous in $\theta$ for almost all values of $x$, then the Fisher information is undefined (or may be considered infinite). However, there is no such thing as "the Fisher information is concentrated around [a point]".

But doesn't it become a continuous function after we perform convolution? The calculation is carried out on the function $f(x;\theta)$ after convolution.

Even after convolution, there can be discontinuity with respect to $\theta$. Also, still, there is no such thing as "the Fisher information is concentrated around [a point]".

Yes. Then, is it okay to discuss the Fisher information amount in the neighborhood of this point? If so, is it calculated in the way I did?

No, there is such thing as "the Fisher information amount in the neighborhood of this point" either.
